# App(installed package) crash immediately after retargeting to WP Silverlight 8.1

Tags: silverlight, exception, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, crash-dumps

My app was retargeted from WP8.0 to WP Silverlight 8.1. Everything runs well no matter Debug/Release mode when I deployed from Visual Studio 2013 to WP8.1 Device. However, when I packed into xap format file and deployed by MS Deployment Tool, the app crash immediately after clicking even no slashscreen.

No too many document found about this on Internet. I am stunked here since 2 weeks. Hope any WP expert could do me a favor, please. Belows is WPA's analysing result of crash dump file if it could help :

```
**Exception Analysis Result**

SYMSRV:  C:\SymCache\KERNELBASE.dll\54742BACbc000\KERNELBASE.dll not found
SYMSRV:  C:\SymCache\KERNELBASE.dll\54742BACbc000\KERNELBASE.dll not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/KERNELBASE.dll/54742BACbc000/KERNELBASE.dll not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/KERNELBASE.dll/54742BACbc000/KERNELBASE.dll not found

FAULTING_IP: 
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+37
777c35d6 b015     add         sp,sp,#0x54

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 777c35d7 (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x00000037)
   ExceptionCode: e0464645
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 1
   Parameter[0]: 88000837

CONTEXT:  00000000 -- (.cxr 0x0;r)
 r0=000005f4  r1=00020000  r2=0141eb60  r3=00000000  r4=778c2451  r5=00000000
 r6=00020000  r7=0141ea48  r8=00000568  r9=0141eb60 r10=0141eb60 r11=0141eb10
r12=00000087  sp=0141ea18  lr=761d40e7  pc=778c2456 psr=00000030 ----- Thumb
ntdll!NtAlpcSendWaitReceivePort+0x6:
778c2456 4770     bx          lr {errorhandlingext!CheckForReadOnlyResourceFilter+0x2fa (761d40e6)}

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

PROCESS_NAME:  aghost.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xe0464645 - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xe0464645 - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  88000837

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

APP:  aghost.exe

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17237 (debuggers(dbg).140716-0327) amd64fre

MANAGED_STACK: !dumpstack -EE
No export dumpstack found

MANAGED_BITNESS_MISMATCH: 
Managed code needs matching platform of sos.dll for proper analysis. Use 'arm or x86' debugger.

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_WRONG_SYMBOLS

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 6e42fa46 to 777c35d6

STACK_TEXT:  
0141fa68 6e42fa46 : e0464645 00000001 00000000 777c35d7 : KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x36
0141fac8 6e440410 : 00000001 00000002 04fc4f98 00c83380 : npctrl!CXcpControl::CPReportError+0x66
0141faf8 6e41608e : 00c83380 00c83290 0141fb28 6e41608f : npctrl!CXcpControl::ReportError+0x10
0141fb08 6e411726 : 04fc4f98 00c83290 00000000 00000401 : npctrl!CXcpDispatcher::OnError+0xc2
0141fb30 6e3fe396 : 00000000 00000401 00000000 00c83290 : npctrl!CXcpDispatcher::OnWindowMessage+0x1275e
0141fb50 76669ce6 : 00c74858 7fd7b000 00c74858 00c603c8 : npctrl!CXcpDispatcher::GroupDispatchProcStatic+0x11e
0141fb80 76669d1e : 8000ffff 00c603c8 6e3fe279 0141fc90 : CoreMessaging!CoreUIConfigureTestHost+0x14aca
0141fbb8 7666672e : 0187bd20 766638d5 0141fc30 7666672f : CoreMessaging!CoreUIConfigureTestHost+0x14b02
0141fbc8 7666a346 : 00000000 00000000 00000000 7666a593 : CoreMessaging!CoreUIConfigureTestHost+0x11512
0141fc38 7666b322 : 0187b118 766ac010 0141fcc8 76664ca3 : CoreMessaging!CoreUIConfigureTestHost+0x1512a
0141fc70 766f396c : 00c38db0 0187b118 00000000 00000000 : CoreMessaging!CoreUIConfigureTestHost+0x16106
0141fcd0 766f3808 : 00000000 00000000 8000ffff 00c49740 : minuser!Core::Yield::IMessageLoopExtensions_Run+0x124
0141fd18 766e74b4 : fffffffe fffffffe 00bf0d40 00bf21d0 : minuser!Core::CoreUIAdapter::DispatchEvents+0x90
0141fd40 69ad81ac : 00000000 0141fdc0 00000000 777731c0 : minuser!minPeekMessageW+0x318
0141fdb0 69ad80c2 : 00000001 00000006 0141fe00 00000001 : windows_ui!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::WaitAndProcessMessages+0xdc
0141fe58 00a324ee : 155bf757 00000002 00000001 00c38000 : windows_ui!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessEvents+0x62
0141fec0 757a24ca : 00c58c08 00c49288 0141fed8 757a24cb : aghost+0x24ee
0141fed0 757a239a : 757a24a5 757d600c 0141ff08 757a239b : twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::Run+0x26
0141fee0 75fdff88 : 0141fef0 00c37fe0 00c325f0 00c37fe0 : twinapi_appcore!CWrlLightweightHandlerBase::ReleaseMarshalData+0x11a
0141ff10 77906426 : 00000000 00b3f740 00000000 00000000 : shcore!SHCreateThreadRef+0x200
0141ffa0 00000000 : 00000000 77906411 00000000 00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x16


STACK_COMMAND:  ~4s; .ecxr ; kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
npctrl!CXcpControl::CPReportError+66
6e42fa46 9b02     ldr         r3,[sp,#8]

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  npctrl!CXcpControl::CPReportError+66

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: npctrl

IMAGE_NAME:  npctrl.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS_e0464645_npctrl.dll!CXcpControl::CPReportError

BUCKET_ID:  ARM_APPLICATION_FAULT_WRONG_SYMBOLS_npctrl!CXcpControl::CPReportError+66

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:wrong_symbols_e0464645_npctrl.dll!cxcpcontrol::cpreporterror

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {e963f9cc-8423-eaea-1bb2-e08acc6d433a}
```

Comment: The framework I used is MvvmCross 3.1.1. It seems one method who creates Singleton is one potential cause. But I don't believe MvvmCross is incompatible with WP Silverlight 8.1.